# Bios does not open after deleting duplicate boot entries

Tags: linux, windows, boot, bios, firmware

I had installed Windows 8.1 Pro. Along with it, I had tried to install Linux with it. After complete Linux installation when I rebooted, I was getting duplicate boot entries in bios setup. I have searched on internet and found this tutorial to delete duplicate entries.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749510%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

I have deleted the boot entries using this tutorial and restarted but now after restart, it stuck on the Lenovo welcome page and says, Press F2 to enter setup and F12 to enter MultiBoot Menu. On pressing F2 or F12, it says "Please Wait" and nothing happens after that.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: What happens if you take out the internal storage?

Comment: Thanks for the reply david. Its the same condition after taking out the HDD too.